# Relative path incorrect in the view layer when hosting a rails3 app in a subdirectory using passenger and apache

Tags: apache-2.2, phusion-passenger, ruby-on-rails-3, directory

I want to host multiple Rails apps on a multiple server using sub-directories.
And have encountered some relative path problems.

I have made a symbolic link to the app's public directory and placed it in the /var/www/html directory,

```
var/www/html/
            /test_app (symbolic link to the public folder of test_app)
```

and set apache as so

```
   LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.12/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
   PassengerRoot /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.12
   PassengerRuby /usr/local/bin/ruby

   <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName  test.com
      DocumentRoot /var/www/html

      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

      RailsBaseURI /test_app

      </Location>
   </VirtualHost>
```

The links in the app itself works just fine, all the links acknowledge the test_app/ directory and work, however, when it comes to showing images in the public directory in the view, the relative path goes wrong.

Say I have

```
/system/files/1/aaa.png
```

it goes looking for it in

```
/var/www/html/system/files/1/aaa.png
```

rather than

```
/var/www/html/test_app/system/files/1/aaa.png
```

As far as I understand this is an Apache setting problem than something to be done in Rails,
if its possible I would prefer to have it contained in the conf file of apache rather than having to alter the code.

Answer (score 2):

You want [RackBaseURI](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#RackBaseURI) rather than  RailsBaseURI for >=3.0